# Why does certificate signed with MD5WithRSA show SHA1 fingerprint?

Tags: cryptography, certificate

When run keytool on a .RSA file for an Android APK I see the following:

```
Serial number: 4a9c4610
Valid from: Mon Aug 31 14:52:16 PDT 2009 until: Sun Sep 25 14:52:16 PDT 2050

Certificate fingerprints:
   MD5:  3F:AD:02:4F:2D:CB:E3:EE:69:3C:96:F3:50:F8:E3:76
   SHA1: 8A:3C:4B:26:2D:72:1A:CD:49:A4:BF:97:D5:21:31:99:C8:6F:A2:B9
   Signature algorithm name: MD5withRSA
   Version: 1
```

Why does it show both SHA1 and MD5 fingerprints even though the algorithm name seems to suggest MD5?

If the question is better answered by me reading some introductory article on this topic, feel free to point me to it.

Answer (score 2):

The fingerprint is simply a hash of parts of the certificate data. It's not related to the hash used in the signature mechanism, so it doesn't have to be MD5.

Comment: +1 SHA-1 over the modulus if I remember correctly... And I remembered [incorrectly](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14330/what-is-the-actual-value-of-a-certificate-fingerprint). That's why I have Google backing up my memory :P Mixed up the PKCS#11 ID of a certificate, which *is* the hash over the modulus...